# TypeError: this.state.propertydetails.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to fetch data from mongodb database to my reactjs front-end using fetch and I keep getting the error above. I've also tried using axios and kept getting the same error. What could possibly be the problem? Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class App extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
      propertydetails: []
     };
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/property')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(propertydetails => this.setState({ propertydetails }, () => console.log('Data fetched', propertydetails)).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    }));

}
render() {
    return (

      <ul>
        {this.state.propertydetails.map(propertydetail => 
          <li key={propertydetail.id}>{ propertydetail.apartmentName}</li>
          )}
      </ul>
        
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the API returns an array. you can also add a guarding condition. it would be nice if you can try console logging the api response and check whether the API returns an array or an object.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class App extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
      propertydetails: []
     };
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/property')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(propertydetails => {
         console.log('propertydetails',propertydetails)
         this.setState({propertydetails});
    })
    .catch(e=>console.log('error', e);

}
render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.propertydetails && this.state.propertydetails.map(propertydetail => 
          <li key={propertydetail.id}>{ propertydetail.apartmentName}</li>
          )}
      </ul>
        
    )
}
}
```